# Pandas reformatting table to make certain rows to column after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, csv

There are a lot of questions about reformatting the table in pandas but unfortunately I couldn't use those for my e.g.

I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dbo.Access_Stat_all.csv',error_bad_lines=False, usecols=['Name','Format','Resource_ID','Number'])
newdf = df[df['Resource_ID'] == 1200]
newdf = newdf[['Format','Name','Number']]

newdf = newdf.groupby(['Format','Name']).last()
print(newdf)
```

Which gives the following( The result is very long, only some lines for e.g.)

```
                 Number
Format Name            
entry  Apr 2006   11
   Apr 2007       3
   Apr 2008       4
   Apr 2011       1
   Apr 2012       3
   Apr 2013       1
   Apr 2014       1
   Apr 2015       1

html   Jun 2017   0
   Apr 2008       4
   Mar 2007       1
   Mar 2013       0
   Mar 2014       0
   Mar 2015       0
   Mar 2016       0
```

I want something like:

```
     Apr 2007   Apr 2008   Mar 2007
Entry  11          4           0
Html    0          0           1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unstacking the result:

```
newdf = newdf.unstack()
```

To remove `Number`, try:

```
newdf.columns = newdf.columns.droplevel()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this reformats the table, but it has one extra top row with "Number" written to it, and If I print it to the file, I will have one top row with only "Number" written to it.  How can I remove it?

Comment: Thanks it worked. Extra question for the sake of beauty, While printing on console(pycharm) It prints with even space but printing on a csv file, it has uneven distance between values, why is that?

Comment: It is comma separated, so the distance between values would depend on whatever application from which you are viewing the file (e.g. Excel).  If it is excel, maybe you can try right formatting the columns.